# RASPBERRY PI Error Python GUI : “no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable”

Tags: raspbian, python, gui, tkinter

Hi guys I want to create a basic GUI with TKinter.

This is my code

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.font

win =Tk()
win.title("Test")
myFont = tkinter.font.Font( family = 'Helvetica', size = 12, weight = 'bold')

def ledToggle():

        print("Hello World")


button1 = Button(win,text ='Test', font = myFont,command = ledToggle, bg='bisque2$
button1.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

I get this error message:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui.py", line 4, in <module>
    win =Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1880, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Why do you have to run `startx` manually, is your desktop environment broken or incomplete? And what kind of display we are talking about? HDMI?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev do you have any ideas for me?

Comment: Its connected with LVDS not HDMI

Comment: How are you launching this program?  Seems like you're doing it from a non-graphical context where there is no display defined...

Comment: this question is not related to the RPi .... it is a linux or python programming question

Comment: I was able to get this all resolved following these steps: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118928/60683 — My program is now launching right as the pi boots up, full screen, before desktop or anything else appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this error usually happens when you access the RPI via SSH, 
you could run:

```
export DISPLAY=0:0
```

or add it to your **bashrc** if you want it to be perminantly excuted on every therminal run and ssh connection.

**EDIT** (a great suggestion by roger-jones):

you can also set the variable by prefixing it to the command: `DISPLAY=0:0 python gui.py`.

If you SSH with PuTTY you can also add the `DISPLAY` to the environment at *"Connection">"Data">"Environment Variables"*

if your not satisfied, check out similar errors as yours:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable)

Comment: For completeness you may want to add that you can also set the variable by prefixing it to the command: `DISPLAY=:0 python gui.py`. If SSHing in with PuTTY you can also add the `DISPLAY` to the environment at *"Connection">"Data">"Environment Variables"*.

Comment: I tried this solution, and It said that it "cannot connect to display 0:0"

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a solution!

```
import Tkinter
import sys
import os

# check if 
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')

master = Tkinter.Tk()
#master.title("tester")
#master.geometry("300x100")
# Lay out label
#label.pack()

# Run forever!
master.mainloop()
```