# Help launching Tkinter on boot Pi 3

Tags: systemd, tkinter

I tried the [example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98944/launch-a-gui-tkinter-program-on-boot/98972#98972) in a [Raspberry Pi SE question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98944/launch-a-gui-tkinter-program-on-boot), creating a systemd ".service" in the past and it worked flawlessly, but now I'm running Tkinter with python3 on a raspberry pi3.

```
[Unit] Description=GUI Start
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0; export XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/ampolas/ampolas.py"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

but I now get a display:0 error like:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display :0.0
```

when I run `echo $DISPLAY` I get `DISPLAY:0.0`. But it seems that on bootup it's not recognized

When I run sudo systemctl daemon-reload,
then ...enable
then ... start
it runs okay, but even `After=grafical.target`, it seems `DISPLAY:0` isn't defined yet

I'm not familiar enough with Linux to understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: You can't start GUI programs with a service file. Use the autostart function of LXDE (search for that on here).

Comment: hey Dougie thanks for the relpy, I did manage to get it to work on another fresh install of  the  raspiOS. But are you suggesting its not a good way to do it? Is there a safer way? This is running a HMI on  an industrial machine,I'm worried that it could fail in future.

Comment: It's not a good way. The services are started before the GUI starts.

Comment: @Dougie Qoute: "*You can't start GUI programs with a service file*" - sorry, but that is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Okay so I got it to work, and it turns out, and I dont know why;  adding this line :

```
# Disable bluetooth
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

to my config.txt file is what caused the error.

I copied that example from this post :

http://himeshp.blogspot.com/2018/08/fast-boot-with-raspberry-pi.html

and it was what caused the display error. No clue as to why, but  I would love to know.

Comment: And what is the solution? Removing `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` from `/boot/config.txt`?

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> when I run `echo $DISPLAY` I get `DISPLAY:0.0`

This is wrong. You must only get the environment value:

```
rpi ~$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
rpi ~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0

rpi ~$ export DISPLAY=DISPLAY:0.0   # WRONG!
rpi ~$ echo $DISPLAY
DISPLAY:0.0
```

Please correct this. Then you should define an environment for the service, not only for the shell script. Try this:

```
[Unit]
Description=GUI Start
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
Environment="DISPLAY=:0.0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"
#ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/printenv
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/ampolas/ampolas.py

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

If this also does not work, then uncomment the `#ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/printenv` to show what environment is given at runtime and what's wrong with it. Reboot and you will find the output with:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl -b
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent 5 hours getting this working just now after trying all of these other solutions under the sun, so let me finally put this to rest.

**Note: This is for raspbian, with main user account using the default username ("pi")**

Here are the steps in order:

---

Name your python file `main.py` and drag your python file to the desktop.

---

Next, create a new plain text file and add the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 /home/pi/Desktop/main.py
```

Save this text file as `launch.command` on the desktop. This is shell script to launch your python file. By default it won't work, we have to chmod it (next step)

---

Run terminal and run the following command:

```
chmod u+x /home/pi/Desktop/launch.command
```

Now double clicking launch.command (and selecting `execute`) will launch your python file.

---

At this point, we are ready to get it launching on boot. **If you've done any other launch attempts prior to this please undo all of those file changes you had done**.

---

Open terminal and run the following:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service`

*We are just going to call it myproject for now, don't change any of this until after you get it working, then feel free to attempt a rename*

---

In the window that pops up, copy paste the following exactly:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Myproject
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0; export XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority; /home/pi/Desktop/launch.command"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Now press ctrl+x to exit-and-save, it will prompt you to save changes, type "y", the filename should already be entered as .../myproject.service, if it is then press enter and it will save and exit, *if the file name is blank it messed up (this just happens sometimes), quit terminal and try all of this again, sorry.*

---

Now in terminal enter:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Then

`sudo systemctl enable myproject.service`

Lastly

`sudo reboot`

---

On launch, before anything else shows (after the boot up splash screen shows of course, but before desktop shows) your GUI will now launch, congrats!

I recommend you launch it full screen, to do that edit your python file to use this:

```
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

**NOTE, 'root' is likely not what you called your TK() init.... at the end of your code you have something like `XXXX.mainloop()`, change 'root' to whatever XXXX is, stick this right after your init of `TK()`**

---

Once you've reboot, you are likely stuck in the app (especially if you launched it full screen), things like alt+f4 or alt+f11 won't kill your program. To exit, press the windows/menu button on your keyboard, the access panel will appear you and can go to accessories>terminal to launch a new terminal window, then run the following:

`sudo systemctl stop myproject.service`

The program will be killed and you will be back to your standard desktop...

NOW, to prevent it from launching again on bootup, simply rename your `launch.command` file to `DISABLED_launch.command` and when you're ready to start launching on bootup again set the name back.

---

Go get a drink, you've earned it.

*Also, you can obviously put these places other than desktop but MAKE SURE you always use the full path in any of these commands, don't use the '~/..' shortcut.*